# Power of -1 in the answer of Reduce command

Tags: equation-solving

Often, when I solve an equation **in the reals** using reduce, it gives me an answer which contains a non-integer power of -1, which is a complex number. It has happened to me several times and always, I could just get the correct solution by throwing away this power of -1. How is this possible? What is it? How do I prevent this from happening, that is, how do I get the result directly without this?

An example:

```
Reduce[d > 0 && 
 n > 1 && (Log[n]*(1/eps^2))^2/
 n <= eps d, {n, eps}, Reals] // ToRadicals
```

gives me

```
d>0 && n>1 && eps >=((-1)^(2/5) log^(2/5)(n))/(d^(1/5) n^(1/5))
```

**Edit:** If I understand correctly, the problem lies in `ToRadicals`. Specifically, it returns the wrong answer. Is there any way I can solve iequalities like this and get a correct answer?

.

Comment: This `Reduce[d > 0 && n > 1 && (Log[n]*(1/eps^2))^2/n <= eps d /. 
   eps -> x^(1/5), {n, x}, Reals] /. x -> eps^5` gives me an inequality `eps^5 >= Log[n]^2/(d n)` implying no minus. For me the solution you have shown looks like a bug.

Comment: The command `Reduce[d > 0 && n > 1 && (Log[n]*(1/eps^2))^2/n <= eps d, eps, Reals]` produces `n > 1 && d > 0 && eps >= Root[-Log[n]^2 + d n #1^5 &, 1]`. One reads in the documentation to `ToRadicals`: "If Root objects in expr contain parameters, ToRadicals[expr] may yield a result that is not equal to expr for all values of the parameters]". Hope this sheds a light on the situation, however, don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: @user64494 thanks very much for the answer. I have expanded the question accordingly. Is there any way to fix/circumvent this?

Comment: With Solve and Reduce it often helps to request a solution for all variables. Why is beyond me. But in your case:Reduce[d > 0 && n > 1 && (Log[n]*(1/eps^2))^2/n <= eps d, {n, eps, d}, Reals] gives: n > 1 && eps > 0 && d >= Log[n]^2/(eps^5 n)

Comment: @user2316602: Sorry, don't understand you. What do you mean by "fix this"?

Comment: Well, the given solution is wrong so I want it to give a solution which is correct.

Comment: Why are you using `ToRadicals` at all? `Root` objects are generally better behaved than expressions involving radicals. `Reduce` without `ToRadicals` gives you the correct solution.

Comment: @JohnDoty, because I am writing a paper in mathematics/theoretical computer science and the reader will be interested in the expression and not in a root object.

Answer (score 2):

When [`ToRadicals`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToRadicals) tries to convert the [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root) object in your inequality, it knows nothing about the conditions on your parameters. To rectify this, you can make use of the undocumented [`Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions) option of [`ToRadicals`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToRadicals):

```
ineq = Reduce[d>0 && n>1 && (Log[n]*(1/eps^2))^2/n <= eps d, {n, eps}, Reals];

ToRadicals[ineq, Assumptions -> d>0 && n>1]
```

> d > 0 && n > 1 && eps >= Log[n]^(2/5)/(d^(1/5) n^(1/5))

Comment: Thank you very much! Do I understand correctly that the problem was that ToRadicals did not know that I want a real solution and it only gave me one of the multiple complex ones? Also, where does one learn about undocumented features?

Answer (score 1):

Mind these are inequalities and not solutions!

If the right-hand side is in the `Complexes` and the left-hand side is `Reals` the inequality does never hold. Both sides are not comparable. And in the example, the roots of -1 are on the unit circle around 0.

The problem comes in with the application of ToRadicals on the result of Reduce. The result of Reduce is an inequality over the reals. It is meant to be solved for example graphical in plotting the inequality.

ToRadicals does know nothing about the constraints and does not even care about them too. It evaluates the chain of logical AND as a list and evaluates only the terms of the chain that can be treated by the methods of `ToRadicals`.

The advantage of `ToRadicals` is that is deals with parameters. Your needs comes from the attributes of Root. It does not automatically express terms in radicals.

A better approach is

```
Reduce[(Log[n]^2)/n <= eps^5 d, {d, n, eps}, Reals]
```

The output is then

```
(d == 0 && 
   n == 1) || (d > 
    0 && ((n == 1 && eps >= 0) || (n > 1 && 
       eps >= Root[Log[n]^2/(d n) - #1^5 &, 1]) || (0 < n < 1 && 
       eps >= Root[Log[n]^2/(d n) - #1^5 &, 1]))) || (d < 
    0 && ((n == 1 && eps <= 0) || (n > 1 && 
       eps <= Root[Log[n]^2/(d n) - #1^5 &, 1]) || (0 < n < 1 && 
       eps <= Root[Log[n]^2/(d n) - #1^5 &, 1])))
```

This shows much more solutions. It does again not automatically express all terms in radicals as desired.

```
Reduce[(Log[n]^2)/n <= eps^5 d, {eps, d, n}, Reals]
```

gives

```
(eps == 0 && 
   n == 1) || (eps > 
    0 && ((d >= 0 && 
       n == 1) || (d >= 4/(
        E^2 eps^5) && (n > 1 || 
         E^(-2 ProductLog[Sqrt[d eps^5]/2]) <= n < 1)) || (0 < d < 4/(
        E^2 eps^5) && (n >= 
          E^(-2 ProductLog[-1, -(1/2) Sqrt[d eps^5]]) || 
         1 < n <= E^(-2 ProductLog[-(1/2) Sqrt[d eps^5]]) || 
         E^(-2 ProductLog[Sqrt[d eps^5]/2]) <= n < 1)))) || (eps < 
    0 && ((4/(E^2 eps^5) < d < 
        0 && (n >= E^(-2 ProductLog[-1, -(1/2) Sqrt[d eps^5]]) || 
         1 < n <= E^(-2 ProductLog[-(1/2) Sqrt[d eps^5]]) || 
         E^(-2 ProductLog[Sqrt[d eps^5]/2]) <= n < 1)) || (d <= 0 && 
       n == 1) || (d <= 4/(
        E^2 eps^5) && (n > 1 || 
         E^(-2 ProductLog[Sqrt[d eps^5]/2]) <= n < 1))))
```

So constrain further for more interesting solution representations.

```
Reduce[eps > 0 && (Log[n]^2)/n < eps^5 d, {eps, d, n}, Reals]
```

The output is

```
eps > 0 && ((d > 0 && 
     n == 1) || (d > 4/(
      E^2 eps^5) && (n > 1 || 
       E^(-2 ProductLog[Sqrt[d eps^5]/2]) < n < 1)) || (0 < d <= 4/(
      E^2 eps^5) && (n > E^(-2 ProductLog[-1, -(1/2) Sqrt[d eps^5]]) ||
        1 < n < E^(-2 ProductLog[-(1/2) Sqrt[d eps^5]]) || 
       E^(-2 ProductLog[Sqrt[d eps^5]/2]) < n < 1)))

Reduce[eps > 0 && n ∈ Integers && 
  n > 1 && (Log[n]^2)/n < eps^5 d, {eps, d, n}, Reals]
```

has

```
Element[n, Integers] && eps > 0 && ((d > 4/(E^2*eps^5) && n >= 2) ||
```

(Inequality[0, Less, d, LessEqual, 4/(E^2*eps^5)] &&
(n > E^(-2*ProductLog[-1, (-(1/2))*Sqrt[d*eps^5]]) ||
1 < n < E^(-2*ProductLog[(-(1/2))*Sqrt[d*eps^5]]))))

ProductLog has a small imaginary part still.

Take attention to this order of the parameters:

```
Reduce[eps > 0 && n ∈ Integers && 
  n > 1 && (Log[n]^2)/n < eps^5 d, {n, eps, d}, Reals]
```

the results are

```
Element[n, Integers] && n >= 2 && eps > 0 && d > Log[n]^2/(eps^5*n)
```

This shows all other possibilities to use `Reduce` are complicated by the parameter on the first position in the set of parameters. Putting n the first place gives the most tautologic result to the input. But this is easiest to understand.

Keep track of the following process for working with `Reduce`:

(a) Simplify the equations first for example with `Simplify`, `FullSimplify.`
(b) Put all parameters in the parameter list in the second argument of `Reduce`.
(c) Enter stepwise all restrictions that match the intents or the question to reduce.
(d) Varied the sequence in which the parameters are entered and use `Reduce` again.
(e) Compare these solutions that match the needs best.
(f) Use `ToRadicals` or a `Plot` whatever show the solutions best. Avoid `Roots` and `ToRadicals` like Mathematica does prefer the output with the least `Roots`.

```
Table[RegionPlot[
  n < Re[E^(-2 ProductLog[-(1/2) Sqrt[d eps^5]])], {eps, 
   0.3, .95}, {d, 0, 24}], {n, 3, 7}]
```

[image: RegionPlot]

```
Table[RegionPlot[d > Log[n]^2/(eps^5*n), {eps, 0.1, 4}, {d, 0, 4}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"eps", "d"}, PlotLabel -> n], {n, 1, 151, 50}]
```

[image: RegionPlot]

It is always very interesting how complicated it is to make a Plot of the region as long as this is possible.

Keep in mind if Complexes can not be avoided to make the functions Reals with Re and investigate the ReIm plots. But better than this is work without Complexes. Mathematica can mix Reals and Complexes and this work is always up to the user to clarify for his personal viewpoint.

This can not cover everything. Think about trigonometric. But the community might help.

This example is not the very best for such a discussion. The receipt works here brilliant in making a table over the iterator n and vary in two dimensions the inequality for example graphically and numerically. Make use in the discussion of the monotony of the function depending on n.

It only shows up how senseful it is to input the inequality nice and meaningful then Solve, Reduce and else work towards easier results representations. The Mathematica documentation does show this process. If there are many parameters these function make trouble, pose long runtime. To solve subproblems graphical first can be an improvement and led to better performances and even give better interpretations of the results.

Use all information given to reduce the numbers of free or limited parameters.

Comment: The statement "The advantage of ToRadicals is that is deals with parameters" kind of conflicts with the documentation. I'm not sure the rest of the response really addresses the actual question.

Comment: This not really my opinion. It is from the documentation: [https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToRadicals.html?view=all] section possible issues: "ToRadicals converts Root objects containing parameters:" and then "The result may not be equal to the Root object for some values of the parameter:"

Comment: You are misinterpreting the documentation. `Root` objects also deal with parameters, so there is no relative advantage there.

Comment: My intend with the answer war to advice that to avoid using `Root` a priori avoids independ of parameters involved to be guided through the `Complexes` by Mathematica methodology. That takes into account Root can deal with parameters but only symbolical. The Root objects are not removed by the use of ToRadicals. And there is advice in the documentation for `Eigensystem` on that too.